# WIX: Logfile generated by MSI has extra space character

Tags: logging, wix, installation, windows-installer

Previously the MSI was creating new logfile everytime, and everything was running smoothly. Now we have a requirement wherein instead of creating a new logfile, we need to append to an existing file. The command we are using is `msiexec file.msi /l*v+ logfile.log  /passive` as msdn suggested '+' should be used to append to an existing file. After this, I'm seeing an extra space after each and every character in the log file.

Sample log file:

> = = =   V e r b o s e   l o g g i n g   s t a r t e d :   2 / 1 5 / 2 0 1 7     8 : 4 9 : 5 4     B u i l d   t y p e :   S H I P   U N I C O D E   5 . 0 0 . 9 6 0 0 . 0 0     C a l l i n g   p r o c e s s :   C : \ W i n d o w s \ S y s t e m 3 2 \ m s i e x e c . e x e   = = =
>
> ```
>                   * * * * * * *   P r o d u c t :   m y f i l e . m s i 
>
>                   * * * * * * *   A c t i o n :   
>
>                   * * * * * * *   C o m m a n d L i n e :   * * * * * * * * * *
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you viewing the logfile with?

Comment: Looks like a multi-byte encoding that your program isn't detecting properly. The first part of every character is probably not used at all for ASCII characters so it just sees it as a space.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - I was using notepad for which I see spaces. But to day I opened the same file using sublime/notepad++, I see something like
`P(nul)r(nul)o(nul)d(nul)u(nul)c(nul)t`
ie., it displays (nul) instead of spaces.

As @BrianSutherland explained, it seems like encoding issue.

How do I get rid of it?
FYI: I'm creating the file using C#, adding some headers, and handing it over to MSI.

Comment: Added a new answer below - I think this should work on Windows 10 at least. I am aware that this is an old question, it came up again since someone added a new answer (a different one).

Comment: Any solutions? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

MSI log files seem to write themselves as UTF-16 (LE). These files can be viewed properly and can be converted back to UTF-8 easily enough with a more robust (and free) text editor like Notepad++, Vim, etc.

In Notepad++ the file will appear normally right when you open it. With that application, you only have to go to the Encodings menu and change it to UTF-8 and then save it so others can view it properly. In Vim, you would need to run this command to view it properly:

```
:e ++enc=utf-16le
```

You can then change its encoding with

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
```

After that, you can save the file with UTF-8 encoding for others to view properly.

Comment: For me I was using `tail` via gitbash, and this answer led me to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196118/prevent-tail-from-modifying-the-charset-of-the-terminal. Basically, pipe the output through a translator that strips the extra UTF-16 junk.  `tail --follow=name my-rolling-file.log | tr -cd "\t\n -~"`.  Works with `cat` as well.

Comment: @Lavamantis - Very nice tip! I just wish Microsoft would stop with defaulting to UTF-16 (LE). It appears PowerShell 7 now defaults to UTF-8 with no BOM like the rest of us finally, so that is a positive development.

Answer (score 1):

***OS Version***: There could be differences between different operating systems here - I have not tested. The below works in Windows 10. My guess would be that Windows 7 might do things differently, or maybe not. I have seen problems in Windows 7 with some command line tool output.

***Windows 10***: In order to create a text file to save MSI logs in, you can write it in **Unicode LE format** as follows (you probably created it as UTF-8):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Sample path:
           // "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test.log";

           // Actual path constructed:
           var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.log");

           File.WriteAllText(path, "This is a string", Encoding.Unicode);
        }
    }
}
```

***msiexec.exe***: Next you run an install as follows and append to the log file specified:

```sh
msiexec.exe /i Setup.msi /l*v+ "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found a way to have a .bat file (e.g. installscript.bat) output to a log file (in ASCII encoding) and then also append/include the log output from msi installer (in UTF-16 encoding) from a separate temporary log file. For example installscript.bat content:

```
REM installscript.bat - outputs log info to logfl in default MS-DOS ASCII format

set logfl=C:\Windows\Temp\install_script_log.txt 
set msilogfl=C:\Windows\Temp\msiinstaller_log.txt

echo "Running msiinstaller.msi ..." >> %logfl%

REM MSI logs in UTF-16 to msilogfl, then output and redirect in ASCII to logfl
.\msiinstaller.msi /quiet /norestart /l* %msilogfl% & TYPE %msilogfl% >> %logfl%

echo "Completed msiinstaller.msi. "  >> %logfl%
```